# ConfigurationFactory from log4j2 not executed in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to load a configuration file (.yaml) to configure log4j2 in a SpringBoot application. Using documentation provided by log4j2 team I am trying to execute a ConfigurationFactory. But nothing is executed. I have to do it when applications starts because there are some properties not defined until this point.

This is the code I have:

```
@Plugin(name = "LoggingConfigurationFactory", category = "ConfigurationFactory")
@Order(10)
public class LoggingConfigurationFactory  extends ConfigurationFactory {
    /**
     * Valid file extensions for XML files.
     */
    protected static final String[] SUFFIXES = new String[] {".yaml", "*"};

   /**
     * Return the Configuration.
     * @param source The InputSource.
     * @return The Configuration.
     */
    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
        return new NuarYamlConfiguration(loggerContext, source);
    }

   /**
     * Returns the file suffixes for XML files.
     * @return An array of File extensions.
     */
    public String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return SUFFIXES;
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to do it, I would appreciate it

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: You just want to load `log4j2.yaml` file, then put this file in `classpath` of the application and it will get loaded automatically.